Formula to return employee codes from a lookup table of names and codes
In Excel, I have five employees each with a unique emploee code.
In column A I have hundreds of rows of these employee names and I want to return each name's corresponding code in column B.
In columns D and E I have the unique list of employee names and their matching codes.
What formula could I use to return the codes in column
B?
Sample Data




A
B
C
D
E




1
Name
Emp code

Available data



2
User1
01Code

Name
Code


3
User2
02Code

User1
01Code


4
user4
04Code

User2
02Code


5
user1
01Code

user3
03Code


6
user5
05Code

user4
04Code


7
user3
03Code

user5
05Code


8
user2
02Code








Probably XLOOKUP (VLOOKUP on older versions).  It depends on how your data is set up.  Might be INDEX/MATCH.
Could you edit your question and include a sample of how your data is set out.

Please note that this site is not a code-writing service. Please show at least what you have tried.

Show what you've tried so far, then ask for help.

Formula in B2
=VLOOKUP(DROP(TOCOL(A:A,1),1),D:E,2,0)


Explanation

VLOOKUP provides the basic functionality:
VLOOKUP (lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])


The lookup_value is DROP(TOCOL(A:A,1),1)

TOCOL returns Column A without any blank rows.
The DROP function is used to remove the heading row Name from the lookup_value.


The table_array is D:E
The col_index_num to return is 2 which is Column E.
The 0 (FALSE) specifies an exact match in case D:E is not sorted in ascsending order.

